# What is the rationale for marking these questions as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I came across [What are the differences between different releases of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183000/what-are-the-differences-between-different-releases-of-ubuntu) earlier today, and noticed that for some reason it ended up being closed as a duplicate of [What is the difference between Ubuntu and its derivatives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives) .

To me, they seem sufficiently different: the former asks for differences between different *releases* of Ubuntu (i.e. Ubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 12.04), while the latter asks for differences between different *derivatives* of Ubuntu (i.e. Ubuntu and Kubuntu).

I just noticed that it was closed as duplicate by multiple people, so I'm wondering if someone can clarify why these are duplicates to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a mistake, I've voted to reopen it. Though it's probably a dupe of this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/111269/what-is-new-in-12-04

Comment: Is it a dupe of that one?

Comment: It probably _is_ a dupe of that other one. I do think, however, that a question which is generalized for all the different releases of Ubuntu would be better than having a new question opened for each new version.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 edit it!